# adding context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); says IIS integrated pipeline required?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, caching

Not sure if this makes sense, but why did adding the code on my http handler (responds to a ajax request returning a json result):

adding `context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`

cause an error and say integrated pipeline mode has to be set?

Answer (score 18):

@homestead, you are doing wrong, you cannot set headers this way, microsoft says:

> "The Headers property is only
>   supported with the IIS 7.0 integrated
>   pipeline mode and at least the .NET
>   Framework 3.0. When you try to access
>   the Headers property and either of
>   these two conditions is not met, a 
>   PlatformNotSupportedException is
>   thrown."

So, if you want to set headers you have to use `context.Response.AddHeader("headerName", "someValue");` instead and your code should add the header successfully.